# How to remove " Archive Record " from Kanban view in Odoo

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-11, kanban

I want to remove the " Archive Record " or " Restore Records " from kanban view settings
see the screenshort

[image]

Select any **Group By** then Settings button then you will see this three options.
**Fold, Archive Records,Restore Record**  . Is there any way to remove these options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove `Archive Record` and `Restore Records` in Odoo 11.0 by override `KanbanView.Group` qweb template.

In your custom module, you will create xml file (for example: kanban.xml) under /static/src/xml/ and you will pate the below xml inside it.

```
<templates>
    <t t-extend="KanbanView.Group">
        <t t-jquery="t[t-if='widget.has_active_field']" t-operation="replace">

        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

Then in the `__manifest__.py` you will add the below:

```
'qweb': [
        `static/src/xml/kanban.xml`,
    ],
```

This will remove these two options for all Kanban views

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's working for the all kanban view in my every odoo module. But i want to do it for a single module / or a single kanban view. Do you know how to do that ?